# iPhone and Webapp sync through iCloud ??

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, icloud

just checking if its possible to sync iOS devices AND a web app through iCloud. Currently we've got an iOS app built, are looking at using iCloud for synching between all the devices and also want a web app component. iCloud would be great to use as the module to sync everything together.

Anyone know if it's possible ?

Comment: Are you asking if you can access things like the key value storage via web as opposed to trying to do so from an iOS or OSX application? Have you checked their safari developer center? Might find something along those lines there if it exists. You can also call Apple Developer Center support and ask them this question directly. You get one free phone call per year of ADC subscription.

Answer (score 11):

I have a similar requirement and have wondered about this too.

Unfortunately iCloud data doesn't seem to be accessible to a Web app. And if you found a hack around it, it would still be an unreliable solution as Apple could always make changes down the road that break your Web component, intentionally or not.

**Edit**: With CloudKit this is no longer true. It comes with a Javascript API for the explicit purpose of providing a web version of your app.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry if I'm misunderstanding the question, but I was looking to add iCloud support to my web app recently and came across the official iCloud JS API. The promo text reads:

> Keep your apps connected and up to date across iOS, OS X, **and now on the web with CloudKit JS**.

[emphasis added]

https://developer.apple.com/icloud/

Answer (score 1):

It is really hard to determine what you mean.... If you are asking if you can implement iCloud in a web app, then I believe that the answer is 'no', since there is only an API for Objective-C for iCloud.

However, you might be able to embed your JS code inside of a native wrapper and write some native code for working with iCloud. However, that may or may not be an option depending on your particular situation.

Edited for spelling.

Comment: "iCould"? No, iCouldn't (resist) :P

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly do this, but only if

- You where running your own server
- The server was running on the iOS platform
- You where able to create software in Objective-C for that server

You could then potentially write a server application, that could be used to connect to the iCloud API, then return the calls back to the end user as Json messages that could be consumed, perhaps by some html interface.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).