# iCloud and a Web Application

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, icloud

I have an iOS app that lets the user manager recipes. I would also like them to be able to manage the same recipes on their iPad and Mac. It seems that iCloud would allow me to do exactly that.

However, if I want to also build a web application that provides the same functionality, am I right in thinking I need my own non-iCloud solution? Is there any iCloud API that lets a user log in to their apple account and access the data added in the iOS/OS X applications?

If I want to allow web access to the data, am I forced to write my own data service and syncing process? Or are there some ways to at least 'connect' the iCloud data to my own user accounts?

Answer (score 5):

I think "native" integration via a web application is impossible:

> [iPhone and Webapp sync through iCloud ??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773920/iphone-and-webapp-sync-through-icloud)

There is actually an iCloud web interface by Apple, but it just has their own apps (contacts, calendar, etc).