# iCloud for web application

Tags: ios, web-applications, icloud

Has Apple provided public API for web applications?
I want to build an application which will be similar to dropbox.
I want the user to be able to manage files and edit them from their devices (iphone/ipad/mac) and from website (any browser based) too.

Is this possible now to see the list of files using iCloud API?

Thanks.

Comment: P.S: I have read this link many times http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625111/icloud-and-a-web-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Apple only provides APIs that can be used within native apps on iOS or OS X devices. There's no documented API that could be used for a browser-based interface to a user's iCloud account (some API apparently exists, since Apple uses it, but third parties do not have access).

Answer (score 2):

As I just stumbled across this thread while searching for a solution for iCloud contacts in my web-app, I just wanted to add that nowadays CloudKit JS seems promising for this use case. It's a bit unfortunate it needs an app on its side, but it's still better than nothing :)

[Can I use iCloud API in web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695497/can-i-use-icloud-api-in-web-application/32095035#32095035)