# Can I use iCloud API in web application?

Tags: icloud-api

I am new for iCloud API.
I want to know can we use iCloud API in web Application ?
Is it possible to access iCloud API via web ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use CloudKit JS

CloudKit JS provides JavaScript APIs for accessing data in your app’s CloudKit containers.

CloudKit JS allows you to build a web interface for users to access the same containers as your CloudKit app running on iOS or OS X. You must have an existing CloudKit app and enable web services to use CloudKit JS.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKitJS/Reference/CloudKitJavaScriptReference/index.html

Comment: Do you know if there is a java api for icloud?

Comment: @Lealo AFAIK, no. And very unlikely to be. Providing more Java doesn't benefit help Apple.

Comment: can we access icloud mail within ios app ?

Comment: There is Java client for accessing iCloud photo public share here: https://gitlab.com/mvysny/icloud-photo-public-share

Answer (score 3):

I got a stackoverflow link which was enough for me to accept that it's not possible

[iPhone and Webapp sync through iCloud ??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773920/iphone-and-webapp-sync-through-icloud)

Thanks,